# How to match inserted and deleted in an update trigger, when the primary key is updated?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, database-trigger

Assume a table like this:

```
tblCostCenters
CCID   nvarchar(10) not null primary key
CCDesc nvarchar(100) null
```

Now there is an "`INSTEAD OF UPDATE`" trigger on this table.
The trigger can use these pseudo-tables:

- `inserted` contains the new records, as they should be updated
- `deleted`contains the old records, before the update

**Now what happens if a user wants to update the primary key itself?**

Assume this statement:

```
UPDATE tblCostCenters set CCID='new' where CCID='old' ;
```

Since the primary key itself has changed, how can the trigger match the records between `deleted` and `inserted` to find out which records should be updated?

Comment: well you shouldnt allow change the primary key in a first place.

Comment: Shouldn't the question be, why does your data structure allow a primary key to change?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The change of primary key is useful in this case.

Comment: @ChrisPickford The change of primary key is useful in this case.

Comment: Since it is set as a primary key, I do not believe the database will allow the user to update that field. But to humor this possible and confusing situation, I would think the `deleted` table have a secondary ID that is in the format of [old ID]-1 or [old ID]-2 and so on.

Comment: @kayla210 assume this: `UPDATE tab set CCID='new' where CCID='old' `

Comment: You can support this use case by adding a new column to the table that isn't user alterable (e.g. uses `IDENTITY`). But most people, at that point, would then mark that column as the PK and just mark `CCID` with a `UNIQUE` constraint. That way it's still unique, it's still referencable by FKs, it's *a* key, just not the PK.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes of course. That would be an "artificial key", while the other is a "natural key". If it's not possible in another way, then I need to do it like this. But since it *is* possible to handle such situations with a normal `update` statement (without triggers), I just wanted to know how to do within a trigger.

Comment: @George - you can't. A logical `update` operation can always be decomposed into a set of `delete`s and `insert`s, which provided they're processed atomically with respect to constraints, will achieve the same logical result compared to the original `update`. And what SQL Server exposes to you is the logically decomposed form.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But assume you are referencing another table with a cascaded update. How would you decompose then an update of a primary key?

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic trick for this - you only have the `inserted` and `deleted` rows to base your match on.  While I understand that there are (very rare) cases where it might make sense to update a PK (and yes, there *are ways to update a PK value*), you have to anticipate situations like this and utilize some form of *alternate key* so that you can match rows even when the PK changes.

So, if you're PK is the *only* way to uniquely identify records, you're out of luck when that changes.  If you have another unique constraint (usable as an alternate key), then that is what you have to use any time the PK is updated.

In summary, if you are going to allow the PK to change, I highly recommend implementing this sort of "backup key" to handle this and any other similar situation, and try as much as possible to limit the circumstances under which this can occur in the first place.

Comment: Yes we have a table where the primary key can change, and we have foreign keys with cascaded updates. So far, it worked good. Only now I need an additional trigger in order to check some constraints, and there I see this issue arising.

Comment: What about using `EXCEPT` to detect PK change?

Answer (score 2):

you cant "update" the primary key. the primary key IS record itself. the work you do - is deleting "unmodifyed pk" and inserting new "modifyed pk". In this way it is clear which records were deleted and which inserted.

Comment: of course you can update primary keys! Assume this: `UPDATE tblCostCenters set CCID='new' where CCID='old' `

Comment: Yes, you can use function UPDATE to make record with "oldPrimaryKey" disappear and record with "newPrimaryKey" appear. But it will logically be a NEW record. there is no another way to identify record except of unique PK. Even on phisical level the old value of PK will be deleted from index and inserted a new one in a new place, in opposite of updating other fields, which can be overwritten in the same place. It is correct way of understanding when you work with PK.

Comment: If you want to say, that depended fields just point to our PK and not stored in a different phisical places - it is wrong. They can be even stored in differents servers. And since they stored in different places - cascade updating is just modifying these fields in another places with some rules.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on [@xdd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37617273/6305294) here is some code:

```
-- Find out [PK]s that have been "added"
SELECT [PK]
INTO #ToInsert
FROM inserted
EXCEPT
SELECT [PK]
FROM deleted

-- Find out [PK]s that have been "deleted"
SELECT [PK]
INTO #ToDelete
FROM deleted
EXCEPT
SELECT [PK]
FROM inserted

-- Change PK by deleting all records where PK is no longer present 
-- and then inserting them as new records
DELETE FROM [Table]
WHERE [PK] IN( SELECT [PK] FROM #ToDelete )    

INSERT INTO [Table]
SELECT *
FROM inserted
WHERE [PK] IN( SELECT [PK] FROM #ToInsert )



-- Update the rest of the data
UPDATE a
SET col1 = I.col1,
    col2 = I.col2,
    ...
FROM [Table] AS a
    INNER JOIN inserted AS I ON a.[PK] = I.[PK]
WHERE I.PK NOT IN( SELECT [PK] FROM #ToInsert )
    AND I.PK NOT IN( SELECT [PK] FROM #ToDelete )
```

Note that conceptually the last update is not needed as you can simply
`DELETE` all `deleted` and `INSERT` all `inserted`
The only case where an actual UPDATE is needed is when you have an `IDENTITY` PK column and you don't want to change it.